# When I try to run my code, I seem to run with an IndexError

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining, unsupervised-learning

When I try to run my code, I seem to run with an IndexError.

```
def _init_trellis(self, observed, forward=True, init_func=identity):
    trellis = [ [None for j in range(len(observed))]
                      for i in range(len(self.real_states) + 1) ]

    if forward:
        v = lambda s: self.transition(0, s) * self.emission(s, observed[1])
    else: 
        v = lambda s: self.transition(s, self.end_state)

    init_pos = 1  if forward else -1   

    for state in self.state_nums():
        trellis[state][init_pos] = init_func( v(state) )
    return trellis
```

> ERROR:
>       v = lambda s: self.transition(0, s) * self.emission(s, observed[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Giving the actual values for the parameters when you are getting this error will help.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
This happens when you try to access a list with an index, but the list does not have that many elements to show.
For example:

```
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(a_list[0]  # Prints a.
print(a_list[2]  # Prints c.
print(a_list[3]  # Gives IndexError. 
'''Index of 3 means the 4th element of the list is being accessed.  
   Since the list only has 3 elements, it gives an index error.'''
```

In this case, observed[1] giving an index error means observed has only 1 element.
That is, `len(observed)` is 1.

---

Original Answer:
Based on the error, ensure that observed is an iterable with a minimum length of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Add assertions to your code.

```
assert(len(observed) > 1)
```

will ensure that the array is long enough.